# How to share ViewModel between Fragments with application context?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

How do I get my Fragments to share the same instance of a ViewModel?

In my ViewModel I need application context so I use "AndroidViewModel" but my MainFragment and DialogFragment don't share the same instace of ViewModel.

How can I achive this?

Here is how I initialized my ViewModels in my MainFragment and DialogFragment:

```java
mViewModel =  ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.
              getInstance(getActivity().getApplication())
              .create(MyViewModel.class);
```

Comment: you can use navigation component it is easy to use. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e